# Eigen: Computation and incrementation of only Upper part with selfAdjointView?

Tags: optimization, eigen

I do something like this to get:

```
bMRes += MatrixXd(n, n).setZero()
.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().rankUpdate(bM);
```

This gets me an incrementation of `bMRes` by `bM * bM.transpose()` but twice as fast.
Note that `bMRes` and `bM` are of type `Map<MatrixXd>`.

To optimize things further, I would like to skip the copy (and incrementation) of the Lower part. 
In other words, I would like to compute and write only the Upper part. 
Again, in other words, I would like to have my result in the Upper part and 0's in the Lower part.

If it is not clear enough, feel free to ask questions.

Thanks in advance.

Florian

Comment: twice as fast as what?

Comment: As computing directly `bM * bM.transpose()` because it knows that the result is a symmetric matrix and just copy the Lower part afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `bMRes` is self-adjoint originally, you could use the following code, which only updates the upper half of `bMRes`.

```
bMRes.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().rankUpdate(bM);
```

If not, I think you have to accept that `.selfadjointView<>()` will always copy the other half when assigned to a `MatrixXd`.

Compared to `A*A.transpose()` or `.rankUpdate(A)`, the cost of copying half of `A` can be ignored when `A` is reasonably large. So I guess you don't need to optimize your code further.

If you just want to evaluate the difference, you could use low-level BLAS APIs. `A*A.transpose()` is equivalent to [`gemm()`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520775), and `.rankUpdate(A)` is equivalent to [`syrk()`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520780), but `syrk()` don't copy the other half automatically.

Comment: Hello @kangshiyin,
thanks for the reply.

Firstly, MatrixXd::Zero(n, n) doesn't work for me.
Secondly, I have this error:
error: 'class Eigen::SelfAdjointView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, 2u>' has no member named 'triangularView'

Comment: @F.Privé I changed my answer.

Comment: `bMRes.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().rankUpdate(bM);` seems to work.

I was sure that I had already tried it, weird. 

Thanks for your help.